# Qt5 Qprocess call command line program to obtain realtime output

Tags: c++, qt, stdout

I use `QProcess` to run another program. The command is `airodump-ng mon0`.
Its output is changing anytime, and is whole different (also not like ping command, changed by line).  I want use `QProcess` to run that program and get its output while it is still running.

### Here is the code:

```
pushButton_clicked()
{
    myprocess = new QProcess(this);
    connect(myprocess,SIGNAL(readReadStandardOutput()),this,SLOT(outlog()));
    myprocess->start("sudo -A ./airodump-ng mon0");
}

outlog()
{
    QString abc = myprocess->readAllStandardOutput();
    textEdit->setText(abc);
}
```

In the program `airodump-ng`, I've already added code `setvbuf(stdout,(char*)NULL,_IONBF,0);` to use row buffering.

Comment: Are you getting no output at all or just not immediately like you are hoping for?

Comment: no output at all,but when i change the commond to ping and add myprocess->waitForFinished(); then it has output.If I havn't use waitForFinished(),it also has no output

Comment: I'm not an expert, but having `sudo` in the command might be a problem if it is waiting for a password, or if what you would get is the output from sudo and not the command it is running.  If you redirect the output when running the command in a shell does it work?  Just wondering if it might be using stderr or something weird.

Comment: Idon't think sudo is a problem.First I use option -A means I use SUDO_ASKPASS so that I don't have to input cipher after sudo.Second I change ping to sudo ping ,it worked just fine, and get my normal ping output.So I still think the problem is in QProcess, maybe I useit the wrong way.T_T

Comment: @Rachael yes, I did solve this somehow after changes: 1. Change from qt5 to qt4 2.add process->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels); after connect.

Comment: @circleone thanks for responding :) --why the downgrade to qt4.2? This `process->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels)` exists in the latest `QProcess` libraries as well. I was never able to end up getting mine to work, but then again I'm using Qt 5.3.btw, I am on Windows, which seems to be causing me much pain in interfacing with QProcess. the System() calls seem to perform much more reliably for things like killing processes, but are not as slick.

Comment: @Rachael what I downgraded for is to fit my arm configuration, and I cannot be sure that it would go well in Qt5.3. But, I think set MergedChannels is needed at least in Qt4.2. It won't work after I remove that. And what's more, I did all my work with Qt is on linux ,Ubuntu and Debian. Killing processes, which is called under sudo, maybe dangerous in Ubuntu, even though you use sudo to call kill. But it works well on Debian.